# Why After pressing the button to upload the file to the one drive , i am getting an error "Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError"

Tags: c#, wpf, onedrive, .net-7.0

Using .net 7.0, I created an WPF application to upload files to the Onedrive using Microsoft Graph Api. I am able to login into my microsoft account but after i click on upload button and then after select the file to upload i am getting this error

Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.
Source=Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.d__28.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.d__20`1.MoveNext() at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.<SendAsync>d__20`1.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.Graph.Me.Drive.DriveRequestBuilder.d__2.MoveNext()
at WpfApp1.MainWindow.d__7.MoveNext() in C:\Users\admin\source\repos\WpfApp1\WpfApp1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 104

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
WpfApp1.MainWindow.UploadFile(string) in MainWindow.xaml.cs

This is my Code, the error comes at var uploadSessionRequestBody = new DriveUpload.CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody
( source from microsoft's documentation)

````
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Authentication;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
using DriveUpload = Microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.Items.Item.CreateUploadSession;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private GraphServiceClient graphClient;
        private bool IsAuthenticated => graphClient != null;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await Authenticate();
        }

        private async Task Authenticate()
        {
            var clientId = "ClientId";
            var redirectUri = "https://localhost/";
            var scopes = new[] { "User.Read", "Files.ReadWrite.All", "offline_access" };
            var tenantId = "Tena ntId";
            IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                .Build();

            var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
            AuthenticationResult result;
            try
            {
                result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                    .WithTenantId(tenantId)             
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
                result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                    .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}")
                    .WithPrompt(Microsoft.Identity.Client.Prompt.SelectAccount)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }

            var accessToken = result.AccessToken;

            graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new CustomAuthenticationProvider(accessToken));
        }

        private async void btnSelectFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
                await UploadFile(filePath);
            }
        }

        private async Task UploadFile(string filePath)
        {
            if (!IsAuthenticated)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please authenticate first.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return;
            }

            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The selected file does not exist.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                var uploadSessionRequestBody = new DriveUpload.CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody
                {
                    Item = new DriveItemUploadableProperties
                    {
                        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "replace" },
                },
                    },
                };

                var myDrive = await graphClient.Me.Drive.GetAsync();
                var uploadSession = await graphClient.Drives[myDrive.Id]
                    .Items["root"]
                    .ItemWithPath(Path.GetFileName(filePath))
                    .CreateUploadSession
                    .PostAsync(uploadSessionRequestBody);

                int maxSliceSize = 320 * 1024;
                using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
                {
                    var fileUploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem>(
                        uploadSession, fileStream, maxSliceSize);

                    var totalLength = fileStream.Length;
                    IProgress<long> progress = new Progress<long>(prog =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {prog} bytes of {totalLength} bytes");
                    });

                    try
                    {
                        var uploadResult = await fileUploadTask.UploadAsync(progress);

                        Console.WriteLine(uploadResult.UploadSucceeded ?
                            $"Upload complete, item ID: {uploadResult.ItemResponse.Id}" :
                            "Upload failed");
                    }
                    catch (ODataError ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading: {ex.Error?.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading: {ex.Error?.Message}");
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error uploading: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

        private class CustomAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
        {
            private readonly string accessToken;

            public CustomAuthenticationProvider(string accessToken)
            {
                this.accessToken = accessToken;
            }

            public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
            {
                request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            }

            public Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(RequestInformation request, Dictionary<string, object>? additionalAuthenticationContext = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
            {
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }
    }
}

            }
        ```


I was expecting files to upload in the my microsoft account but i got the error.
````

Comment: Could you share more details? Which line throws the exception? What's the error message? Try to click on View Details to check the error code and the error message.

Comment: At line number 104 it throws the error , this code line
 var myDrive = await graphClient.Me.Drive.GetAsync();

Comment: here are the details of the error, Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.
  Source=Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary